# Simple Numpy Vectorization

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two 1D Numpy arrays `start` and `stop`, both of which contain integers (which are used to index some other array). I have the following piece of code.

```
index_list = []
for i in range(len(start)):
    temp = range(start[i], stop[i])
    index_list.extend(temp)
index_list = np.array(index_list)
```

Is there a simple way to vectorize this?

Comment: You mean like `np.concatenate([np.arange(frm, to) for frm, to in zip(start, stop)])` but vectorized?

Comment: The current implementation is pretty fast.  If using python2.x, you could shave off a few 10s of nanoseconds using `index_list += t`, but it's currently quite fast (4us on my machine for small `start/stop`).  How long is `start`?

Comment: Does the length of `range(start[i], stop[i])` vary across rows, or is it constant?

Comment: Exactly. I'm sure there's an easy way to do it but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: `start` and `stop` will have up to ~100k elements, and `range(start[i], stop[i])` will also vary from having a length of 0 to about 10 I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can vectorize this as follows:

```
def make_index_list(start, stop):
    lens = stop - start
    cum_lens = np.cumsum(lens)
    # Sequential indices the same length as the expected output
    out = np.arange(cum_lens[-1])
    # Starting index for each section of `out`
    cum_lens = np.concatenate(([0], cum_lens[:-1]))
    # How much each section of `out` is off from the correct value
    deltas = start - out[cum_lens]
    # Apply the correction
    out += np.repeat(deltas, lens)

    return out
```

With some made up data:

```
start = np.random.randint(100, size=(100000,))
stop = start + np.random.randint(1, 10 ,size=start.shape)
```

We can take the code for a test ride:

```
In [39]: %%timeit
   ....: index_list = []
   ....: for i in range(len(start)):
   ....:     temp = range(start[i], stop[i])
   ....:     index_list.extend(temp)
   ....: index_list = np.array(index_list)
   ....:
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit make_index_list(start, stop)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.27 ms per loop

In [41]: np.array_equal(make_index_list(start, stop), index_list)
Out[41]: True
```

So it is correct and about 15x faster, not bad at all...

Answer (score 2):

If you're prepared to get your hands dirty, you can speed it up quite significantly using [Cython](http://cython.org/)

Original function, for reference:

```
import numpy as np

def original_indices(start, stop):
    index_list = []
    for i in range(len(start)):
        temp = range(start[i], stop[i])
        index_list.extend(temp)
    return np.array(index_list)
```

Cythonized version:

```
#!python
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def cython_indices(Py_ssize_t[:] start, Py_ssize_t[:] stop):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t final_size, count, ii
        Py_ssize_t[:] index_array
    final_size = 0
    for ii in range(start.shape[0]):
        final_size += stop[ii] - start[ii]
    index_array = np.empty(final_size, dtype=np.int64)
    count = 0
    for ii in range(start.shape[0]):
        idx = start[ii]
        while idx < stop[ii]:
            index_array[count] = idx
            idx += 1
            count += 1
    return index_array
```

Some fake data:

```
start = np.random.random_integers(0, 1000, size=100000)
stop = start + np.random.random_integers(0, 10, size=100000)
```

Some timings:

```
%timeit original_indices(start, stop)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 79.4 ms per loop

%timeit cython_indices(start, stop)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop
```

Cython speeds things up by an order of magnitude compared with the original version.